# Install SSL certificate on several Windows 2008 servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl

Are there any tools for installing a SSL certificate across a farm of Windows Server 2008 machines?

Comment: Do you importing a CA certificate for multiple servers/workstations to recognize or do you mean a shared certificate such as for a load-balanced web farm?

Comment: Load-balanced web farm.

Comment: Is that web farm behind an ISA or similar? Otherwise you will need a unique SSL certificate per server, and doing that with Group Policy, as I suggested below, might now work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Group Policy for this. I am assuming those servers are members of a domain. Please clarify and I will post the steps, if needed.

Comment: Servers are not members of a domain, but the steps would be helpful to others seeking the information on this site regardless.